# How can I find all Featured Articles with pywikibot?

Tags: python, pywikibot

I have this piece of code that find all the wikipedia articles that have the template dubious using the library pywikibot:

`pages = pywikibot.Page(site, "Template:Dubious").getReferences(namespaces = 0)`

Now I need to find all Featured articles. I guess that it can be done using the right search string, but I don't know which is.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Wikipedia, then I assume you can use the features of [CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:CirrusSearch#Intitle_and_incategory). This should work:

```
pages = list(site.search('incategory:"Featured articles" hastemplate:"Dubious"'))
```

Of-coarse, if you are using a non-English Wikipedia, then you'll have to replace the `Featured articles` with the localized name of that category.